# Coordinate system for a strategy game

Tags: coordinates, hexagonal-grid

I am working on a personal project of developing a simple 3D strategy game. I am working on my own game engine (let's assume that I have to have my own) and I have one theoretical question. How to develop a suitable coordinate system, which would be scalable and provide the best versability?

I am deciding between a X,Y coordinate system (different units cover different space - simply rectangle shaped) and a hexagonal system (bigger units take more hexagons).

I am working here with a simple concept of three different units of three different sizes for every player (maybe even buildings) and collision detection with conflict resolution. Thanks.

Comment: There's no correct answer to this question. It just depends on the details of your game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amit Patel wrote a great entry all about hexagonal coordinate systems at http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/ and I strongly encourage you to read through the whole thing for a deeper understanding.

A system he mentions in there that happens to be my personal choice for such systems is the Cube Coordinate system; In this system, three numbers are given to determine location of the hexagon (to match the 3 axes of a hexagon):

[image: Description of cube axes]

There are a couple of advantages to this system with the biggest one being that the three values of a hexagon's location when added will all equal zero. That is to say, X + Y + Z = 0. This is also what allows you to further simplify the system into Axial Coordinates; Because X + Y + Z always equal 0, then you can remove one of the axes and still have enough information to determine a position. If X = -1 and Y = 1, and Z is left undefined, it's easy to determine that Z = 0.

Comment: Btw, a hexagonal grid is actually a square grid with only one diagonal directional allowed.  That's why in the cubic coordinate system X+Y+Z=0. e.g. drop the Z axis entirely and you'll be fine (you just have to remember the skew).